# CakePHP 2: How to run method generate from SchemaShell class in Controller

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0, shellexecute

I want to generate "schema.php" from an action in a controller. I've tried:

```
$m = new SchemaShell();
$m->params = array('force');
$m->generate();
```

but this doesn't work. Displays a couple of Notice.

How to make it work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

```
$m = new SchemaShell();
$m->params = array('force' => 1, 'file' => 'schema.php');
$m->startup();
$m->generate();
```